# How to identify in Eclipse PDE the plugin or dependency that provides a package?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am facing many instances of the following error message in the process of migrating an Eclipse plugin from Java 8 to Java 11. The build is using Tycho, but I'm not sure that matters much.

```
The package org.xml.sax.helpers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
…
```

The message is explicit. The solution I consider is excluding the dependency that causes the duplication since this is now provided by the runtime environment.

My problem is that the target platform that I am using includes hundreds of JAR files and I can't sift through the uncompressed version of each file to find out which one provides the packages.

If I could identify the dependency, or have the Java compiler write a more detailed error message, that would help me solve the issue.

Therefore, I used https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer to search my Maven dependencies and the plugins folder of my target platform (Eclipse 2020-09), to no avail.

Is there in PDE a possibility to identify the plugin that provides a specific Java package?

Comment: There was a javax.xml plugin included with Eclipse up to release 4.6

Comment: Use _Search > Java Search..._ with the option _Application libraries_ to find the plugins that provides a specific Java package.

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I found java.xml was among the platform libs. I also found the `filters` option of Tycho plugin `target-platform-configuration` to exclude specific packages from the target platform, but an osgi bundle required it. I solved the issue by downgrading the source level from 11 to 8.